# Can't find any CSS filter on this image eventhough it's displayed differently than source

Tags: html, css, image, filter, background-image

I'm trying to replicate [trainline](https://www.thetrainline.com/it)'s website as a web developer course's daily project and I wanted to imitate it as similar to the original as I can.

So, I was trying to set up the `background-image` (currently assigning it as `<body>`'s `background-image` in CSS) after I downloaded it directly from the website's HTML code; the image's link can be found searching for `eu-23.1x.jpg` in the page's HTML.

However, once I found the background image link, [here](https://www.thetrainline.com/content/WEB/images/home/hero/eu-23/eu-23.1x.jpg), I saw that the sky's color is much brighter than what's displayed on the website. They somehow added a filter to the image darkening the sky, and that enabled them to put white text (the headings in the hero section) without any accessibility issues.

I then searched for any CSS filter the added to the image to try and replicate the sky darkening effect but I found none. The image has no filter, no hue, no saturation, no overlayed `div` with a `background-color` or anything.

How did they darken the sky without any CSS or overlays? Am I missing some CSS classes or overlayed tags?

Comment: You may need to share further information, looking at the website, I can't see where that image is being used. I would hazard a guess thought that there is potentially some styling that you've not spotted. I could be an overlay div or CSS elsewhere on the site, perhaps on the heading text themselves?

Comment: @Harrison yes, as you suggested and as @Asaf Sanany then noted, there's a top overlay `div` with a background gradient color just on top of that image. I couldn't find it alone even though I searched through the code for a long time lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look at the class with the `<div class="_1oxc7jv4" data-test="home-banner-container-eu"><div>` selector.

it has a `::before` attribute with `background: linear-gradient(to bottom,rgba(21,82,126,.7),rgba(21,82,126,0));`, which is responsible for the darkened background.

notice this is a gradient that is on top of the image and comes from the header (the element mentioned above).

Comment: Damn, I've search through HTML for dozens of minutes but didn't noticed that div. Thanks you SO MUCH, you're awesome!